# Angular ng-select (Editable Input) should allow only number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, angular-ngselect

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-555ova?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

In Angualr ng-select we can choose value from drop down, or we can add new value by typing in the select box. Now i want select box should allow only numberfor typing new value (am expecting like input type number).

Ref screenshot for error.
[image]

Comment: Apparently there's a similar question on their GitHub and the API allows it: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/136

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev there doesn't seems to be any keypress event on `ng-select`. The search event also seems to be kind of buggy, assuming it actually works.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev - The input tag is dynamically generating, can't directly write keypress event for input tag.